# How to call other functions from within Elixir GenServer handler?

Tags: function, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a GenServer that implements functionality for a single item, e.g:

```
def handle_call({:sync, id}, _from, state) do
    ## update data
    {:reply, data, sync}
end
```

Now I want to handle this functionality for multiple ids, e.g.:

```
def handle_call({:sync_all, ids}, _from, state) do
    ## call sync for each id
    data = Enum.map(ids, fn(id) ->
        GenServer.call(self(), {:sync, id})
    end)
    ## Further reduce down data to stats
    {:reply, data, sync}
end
```

This however does not work telling me that the process attempted to call itself.

I assume this must be due to the blocking nature of `call`. The same however happens if I use `cast` in the `sync_all` version.

So my question is: How can I call other `GenServer` tasks from within a `handle_call` or `handle_cast` function?

Comment: `cast` should work inside `handle_call`. Can you post the version of the code which does that and didn't work for you?

Answer (score 8):

What you would normally do in such cases is to extract the common logic to a separate function:

```
def handle_call({:sync, id}, _from, state) do
  {data, state} = do_sync(id, state)
  {:reply, data, state}
end

def handle_call({:sync_all, ids}, _from, state) do
  {data, state} = Enum.map_reduce(ids, state, &do_sync/2)
  {:reply, data, state}
end

defp do_sync(id, state) do
  # do something
  {data, new_state}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Making a GenServer call to the same process does not make a lot of sense. A process handles one message at a time. A call will wait for an answer. However, the process cannot answer until it is finished with the current message. The code you have will time out waiting for an answer since the process never finishes handling the current message, and thus never handles the one sent with the call.

In general, you use casts and calls to define an interface for other processes to send messages to the process. You could model the actual data transformations as pure functions, and then call these as needed from each of the two handler functions.